# Returning objects from a class property to a dictionary

Tags: c#, object, model

I'm looking for a way to return properties in a class, back into a a dictionary. Let me give an example...

If you have a model like this:

```
public class MyModelTemplate
{
    string TestString { get; set; }
    bool TestBool { get; set; }
}
```

And give it some values in the setter:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public MyModelTemplate Model_one
    {
        get { return Model_one; }
        set { value.TestString = "I am a string"; value.TestBool = true; }
    }

    public MyModelTemplate Model_two
    {
        get { return Model_two; }
        set { value.TestString = "I am a string TWO"; value.TestBool = false; }
    }
}
```

Would it be possible to make a function and put the items in a Dictionary?

```
  public static Dictionary<string, object> GetValuesFromModel(object model)
    {
        // Return the object from the model in a dictionary
        return strReturnValues;
    }
```

Comment: please explain how you want your output

Comment: So by using the method called GetValuesFromModel() I want to return TestString and TestBool in a dictionary.. like this:
So I can use it in a loop later
var modelone = GetValuesFromModel(Model_one)

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen when you do this `set { value.TestString  = "I am a string"; value.TestBool = true; }`? How is anyone supposed to use `TestClass`? Why is `Model_two` outside a class? What is `table`? How are those classes related to the question? Please read [ask]

Comment: There we go... rephrased the question a bit. Hope its more clear now. I also fixed the class confusion.

Comment: Give your code a test and see what happens - hint: it won't work, at all, as you would expect. This `get { return Model_two; }` is just a `StackOverflowException` when called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties in `MyModelTemplate` must be public.

You got it wrong with `TestClass`. Try this

```cs
public class TestClass
{
    // Constructor
    public TestClass ()
    {
        Model_one = new MyModelTemplate{ 
            TestString = "I am a string", TestBool = true };
        Model_two = new MyModelTemplate{ 
            TestString = "I am a string TWO", TestBool = false };
    }

    public MyModelTemplate Model_one { get; set; }

    public MyModelTemplate Model_two { get; set; }
}
```

A solution with a dictionary instead of properties:

```cs
public class TestClass
{
    public Dictionary<string, MyModelTemplate> Models { get; } =
        new Dictionary<string, MyModelTemplate>();

    public TestClass()
    {
        Models.Add("Model_one", new MyModelTemplate{ 
            TestString = "I am a string", TestBool = true });
        Models.Add("Model_two", new MyModelTemplate{
            TestString = "I am a string TWO", TestBool = false });
    }
}
```

Now, you can access the dictionary like this

```cs
var test = new TestClass();
var model = test["Model_one"];
Console.WriteLine(model.TestString);
Console.WriteLine(model.TestBool);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) in such cases. Please have a look on the code below -

```
public static void Main()
{
    var model1 = new MyModelTemplate() {TestString="A", TestBool = true};
    foreach(var pair in GetValuesFromModel(model1)){
        Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key} - {pair.Value}");
    }
}

public static Dictionary<string, object> GetValuesFromModel(object model)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    var props = model.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach(var prop in props){
        result.Add(prop.Name, (object)prop.GetValue(model));
    }
    return result;
}
```

It should give you following output on console -

```
TestString - A
TestBool - True
```